# List/Dictionary Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I am building two lists and one dictionary out of the comprehension technique. For the first list, I want to write a list comprehension statement to filter the list x by eliminating all elements that have values greater than or equal to 17. This is what I have, but cannot manage to put in the numbers, just the Boolean value:

```
X = [9, 34, 12, 83, 13, 10, 3, 9, 4]
xSmall = [x < 17 for x in X]
```

For the second list, I want to write a list comprehension statement that filters the list x by extracting only the even numbers. Again, I seem to be cursed with only getting the Boolean values:

```
x = [2, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 2, 8, 12]
xEven = [x%2 == 0 for x in x]
```

And lastly, I want to build the dictionary in this manner: Use the dictionary y as an input into a dictionary comprehension statement that creates a new dictionary, yEvenKey, which contains the key-value pairs from y if the key of that pair is an even integer. Here is what I manage to get so far: I don't want to use any module; just good old comprehension technique:

```
y = {2: 'no', 3: 'yes', 4: 'gato', 6:'Cheval',1:'!'}
yEvenKey = {y: if y.keys() % 2 == 0}
```

Comment: You are placing the condition where you should place the final expression that gets inserted in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xSmall = [x for x in X if x < 17]
```

`x < 17` is a condition, it returns a boolean.

```
xEven = [x for x in x if x%2 == 0]
```

again, `x%2 == 0` is a condition.

```
yEvenKey = {k: v for k, v in y.items() if k%2 == 0}
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) the link to the Python docs.